# Case statement is outside switch

Tags: java, android

I'm doing some experimenting trying to get a toggle button to move a image view depending on if the button is pressed or not. currently it is stating that the case is outside of the switch and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
switch(v.getId())

{
    case R.id.moveButton: {


        boolean check = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();
        if (check) {
            ImageView img_animationOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.player);

            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(.0f, 200.0f,
                    0.0f, 0.0f);
            animation.setDuration(1000);
            animation.setRepeatCount(1);
            animation.setRepeatMode(2);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            img_animationOne.startAnimation(animation);

        } else {
            ImageView img_animationOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.player);

            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(200.0f, 0.0f,
                    0.0f, 0.0f);
            animation.setDuration(1000);
            animation.setRepeatCount(1);
            animation.setRepeatMode(2);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            img_animationOne.startAnimation(animation);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: remove the brackets after case R.id.moveButton:

Comment: You might want to read some [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: i figured out a different way to accomplish what i was trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this.This is the actual syntax for swtich case statements.

```
switch(v.getId())

    {
        case R.id.moveButton: 


            boolean check = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();
            if (check) {
                ImageView img_animationOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.player);

                TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(.0f, 200.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f);
                animation.setDuration(1000);
                animation.setRepeatCount(1);
                animation.setRepeatMode(2);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                img_animationOne.startAnimation(animation);

            } else {
                ImageView img_animationOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.player);

                TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(200.0f, 0.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f);
                animation.setDuration(1000);
                animation.setRepeatCount(1);
                animation.setRepeatMode(2);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                img_animationOne.startAnimation(animation);

            }
    break;

        }
```

If the above did not work, convert the switch statement into an if-else statement.
In a regular Android project, constants in the resource R class are declared like this:

```
public static final int main=0x7f030004;
```

However, as of ADT 14, in a library project, they will be declared like this:

```
public static int main=0x7f030004;
```

In other words, the constants are not final in a library project. Therefore your code would no longer compile.
To convert into if statement,
In Android Studio
Move your cursor to the switch keyword and press `Alt` + `Enter` then select

> Replace 'switch' with 'if'

Comment: thanks, this got rid of the problem with the case not being inside the switch and the break thing swell. but know its saying a constant expression is required for R.id.movebutton:

Answer (score 2):

You forgot

```
break
```

So you run all code after label `R.id.moveButton` every time.

That should be

```
case R.id.moveButton:
    //your code
    break;
```